# Image Size Android Upload PHP

Tags: php, android, image, upload, resize

In my App User are able to upload some Images in Android to a Web Server with php.
What image size would you prefer? 
I want to resize the image before uploading and I don't know which size would be the best...
And which quality would you prefer? Which is the best quality, for a small file size and an accetable image quality?

Last question. The Users can doanload the image in a ListView. then after clicking on it they can see the image in a big imageview. Would you create the thumbs on the fly in php or would you save an thumb when uploading? If you would save when uploading, please tell me a good size and quality for thumbs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are too many questions in this. :) Let me try.

a. While uploading the image things to be kept in mind are speed of the network as well as the capacity of the phone. You could upload say a max_width/max_height of 1024px on a 2.5G network connection. However if you want to upload many images at a time, you would be better off reducing the size further.

b. While downloading, you should download the entire image and save it on file system. For listview you should scale the image to thumbnail size while reading and show with scale=1 for full-blown image.

c. One can convert the image to base64 while uploading it and then on the server side convert it back to png/jpg.

d. JPEG with 75% quality and max_width/max_height of 1024 has been working fine for me.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. I want to download thumbs for listview because i think it's too much traffic download all the big images. Isn't there any performance problem scaling down images on the fly with php?

Comment: If you are downloading thumb for listview, then you need to also download larger images when the user wants to see them. For the other question, while saving also save thubnails on the server along with full-blown image. Either ways it should work if you server is of good configuration and the traffic is not in 100s of hit per second.